# How to create FK to table partitioned by date in PG12

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, postgresql-12

Is it possible to create FK to table partitioned by daterange in PG12?

Imagine I have big table `user_session` and `event` table with FK to it:

```
create table user_session(                       -- BIG TABLE to be partitioned
    id         bigserial primary key,
    created_at timestamptz not null default now(),
    some_info  text
);

create table event(
    id      bigserial primary key,
    user_id bigint references user_session (id), -- FK
    data    text
);
```

The first idea was to create new schema like this:

```
create table user_session(
    id         bigserial primary key,
    created_at timestamptz not null default now(),
    some_info  text
) PARTITION BY RANGE (created_at);
```

But it fails with error:
`Detail: PRIMARY KEY constraint on table "user_session" lacks column "created_at" which is part of the partition key.`

Ok, lets make PK with two columns:

```
create table user_session(
    id         bigserial,
    created_at timestamptz not null default now(),
    some_info  text,
    primary key (id, created_at)
) PARTITION BY RANGE (created_at);
```

However, now I cannot create table `event`:
`[42830] ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "user_session"`.
I also cannot create unique constraint by hand.

---

In most Postgres articles there is code with no PK on partitioned table:

```
create table user_session(
    id         bigserial,
    created_at timestamptz not null default now(),
    some_info  text,
) PARTITION BY RANGE (created_at);
```

However, now I cannot create `event` table:
`[42830] ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "user_session"`

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's a (serious) limitation of the partitioning in Postgres: the primary key must contain in the primary key.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the problem is that I do not need to partition by that key. I do not want to create PK with `created_at`, only `id`. But Postgres insists on it during partitioning

Comment: I understand that, but as I said: it's a hard (and annoying) limitation of the way partitioning is implemented in Postgres.

Comment: Yeah, I thought this was supported. I don't see how. You cannot create a unique constraint on the parent table with just the id column, okay I get that because there is no way to enforce uniqueness in the child paritions... Yet you cannot reference just the ID column. As far as I can tell it does not work - you must either partition on the primary key which probably what 99% of people don't want to do...